# How to generate java code from sequence diagram in visual paradigm?

Tags: uml, visual-paradigm

How to  generate java code from sequence diagram in visual paradigm?

It's always out a message " [Warning] There is no class model available for code generation.",I don't know what can I do about this.

Answer (score 1):

This should be caused by you picked the wrong folder as the source folder for perform [reverse your source code to sequence diagram](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/features/code-engineering-tools/#reverse-sequence-diagram). The source folder you specified should the parent folder of the root of your source, i.e. if your classes are in package like **com.vp.sample**, then you should **select the parent folder of "com"** as the source folder for perform reverse engineering.

The article below explains this in details.
https://knowhow.visual-paradigm.com/uml/why-arent-there-any-operations-to-choose-from-in-reverse-engineering-of-sequence-diagram/